# Unable to create memory segment when running 2 instance of Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql

The server it self only have azure A0 configuration (750 MB).

I'm trying to run 2 instance of Postgresql. Looks like I'm only able to run one of it on the same time. The second instance always failed to run with "Unable to create memory segment" error. Is there any configuration I can change to mitigate this issue?

PostgreSQL version 9.5

Windows server 2012 datacenter

shared_buffers 128 MB (changed to 64 MB still not working)

Comment: To answer this question, more information is needed: 1) PostgreSQL version 2) operating system 3) PostgreSQL configuration (particularly `shared_buffers`) 4) the lines from the PostgreSQL server log including the exact error message.

Comment: PostgreSQL version 9.5
windows server 2012 datacenter
shared_buffers 128 MB (changed to 64 MB still not working)
I don't have the server log at this moment..

Comment: Please edit the question to add this and the other information.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the config

```
dynamic_shared_memory_type = windows
```

to

```
dynamic_shared_memory_type = none
```

I can run 2 instance in the same time after that.